# Jsp Include and form submission

Tags: jsp

I have a JSP page  to which i have included a  file header via include but when i submit form  am not getting the   form submitted values as expected.I removed the included file and submitted values are coming.The included page earlier had a form action tag i removed the action tag now still it remains same..now included page only have form no action tag. i cant trace out whats wrong.

Main.jsp  included with header.jsp

Regards
Mandan

```
Main file which have a include .  Am not getting the action variable value in submitted page

     <%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="img/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/w3.css">

    <style>

    </style>

    <style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function submitme(c) 
    {
    //alert(c); 
    if(c==1)
    {
        document.getElementById("action").value = "getPMO";
        }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("action").value = "getALLPMO";  

    }
    alert(document.getElementById("action").value); 
    document.forms["findPMO"].submit();                    

    }

    function logmeout()
    {
    alert("logging out from parent");  
    document.getElementById("action").value = "logout"; 
    document.forms["findPMO"].submit();  
    }





    </script>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head> 
    <body >


    <form  id="findPMO" name="findPMO" action="Operation.jsp"  method="post"> 

    <jsp:include page="Board.jsp"/>

        <table width="75%" border="0" align="center"> 
            <tr>
                <td align="center"  colspan="2"> 
                    <h4>

                        <h3><u>Find This PMO details</u></h3> 
                    </h4>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td align="center"><b>PWO Number</h5>&nbsp;<input type="text" name="PMOnumber" id="PMOnumber"><Input type="submit" value="Find Details" onclick="submitme(1)">
                <Input type="submit" value="Details" onclick="submitme(2)">
                </td>  
            </tr> 

        </table>





    <input type="hidden" id="action" name="action">       


    </form> 
    </body>
    </html>



submitted page Operation.jsp


<%@ page java.text.*,java.util.Date,java.util.*"
    language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>   
</head>
<body>




<%
System.out.println("hai");
String action=request.getParameter("action");     
System.out.println("hai"+action);  

%>








Included page  



<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<script type="text/javascript">

function showout()
{
alert("logging out");
document.getElementById("action").value = "logout";     
document.forms["dataSaveResult"].submit();   
}

</script>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head> 
<body >
<body bgcolor="#ccdcff">

<script language=JavaScript>


var message="!";

///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
//alert(message);
return false;
}
}

function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
//alert(message);
return false;
}
}
}

if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false") 

// --> 
</script>
<form>  

</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show. Your. Code.

Comment: Thank you jozef...i will add code